# Is it reasonable to put public and private keys under different chapters in “authorized_keys”?

Tags: authentication

I want to ask as a newbie, is it reasonable by means of Unix architecture to put both public keys and private keys under different chapters in `authorized_keys` file?

I personally put only public keys in /.ssh/authorized_keys, and put every private key in an independent file.

When I execute an SSH command, I just include a reference to the private key in the command itself, like this:

`sudo ssh mastik@999.999.999.999 -L 80:localhost:80 -i home/mastik/.ssh/mastik_pri`

I do so as I know that the evaluation for authorized_keys is different then the more specific or precise evaluation of each private key.

Yet, I would still like to ask this for newbies who might get a bit confused in the question if it's legitimate or actually logical to put both types of keys in the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `authorized_keys` file is *only* for public keys.  There is no use case for including private keys.

`authorized_keys` resides on the ssh server; the private keys stay on your client machine.